# Can't load image with html

Tags: python, html, image

I've been trying to upload an image in my webpage where i have multiple directories. I tried loading the image when the file was in the same directory as index.html. I tried loading the image when the file was in the directory templates and i even tried to make a directory images and upload it from there but nothing works. As you can see from the image, I copied the path and the relative path(i tried both) and put int "img src" but the image just won't load. The terminal says that it can't find the image due to a 404 error and gets me a link but when i click the yellow link I am able to see the picture. What else can i try?

[codespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4mql.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text. Screenshots of code can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I managed to do it!! I was supposed to create a static folder and to the path like ./static/image

Comment: Again, this is another of the countless posts on SO and all over the internet where the solution is almost always the same.

Answer (score 0):

try relocating your image where your html file is and changing the type of file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What do you mean by changing the type of file?

Comment: what. This has nothing to do with either file types but only the both locations of the .html and .jpg file

Answer (score 0):

`index.html` resides in `/templates` and your relative path would lead to `/templates/workspaces` which obviously does not exist.

You can do something like

```
<img src="slika.jpg">
```

if the `index.html` and `slika.jpg` are in the same directory.

Comment: I did that @raizo but it doesn't work so i tried with the path

Comment: well the path is wrong